# ValueError: Input 0 of node incompatible with expected float_ref.**

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pycharm, tensorflow-lite

I'm getting below exception while trying to import my optimized frozen graph.

```
# read pb into graph_def
with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# import graph_def
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

Getting the exception in this line:

```
tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)
```

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/automator/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.5/site-
>   packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 489, in
>   import_graph_def
>          graph._c_graph, serialized, options)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
>   tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: Input 0 
>   of node
>   import/final_retrain_ops/Wx_plus_b/weights_quant/AssignMinLast was
>   passed float    from
>   import/final_retrain_ops/Wx_plus_b/weights_quant/min:0 incompatible
>   with    expected float_ref.   During handling of the above exception, 
>   another exception occurred:  Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/snap/pycharm-community/64/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1664, 
>   in   
>          main()   File "/snap/pycharm-community/64/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1658, in
>   main
>          globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)   File "/snap/pycharm-community/64/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py", line 1068, 
>   in run
>          pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script   File
>   "/snap/pycharm-community/64/helpers/pydev/_pydev_imps/_pydev_execfile.py",
>   line 18, in execfile
>          exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)   File "/home/automator/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tfliteme.py", line 389,
>   in   
>          printTensors("/home/automator/Desktop/cervix/optimized_model.pb")
>   File "/home/automator/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/tfliteme.py", line
>   374, in   printTensors
>          tf.import_graph_def(graph_def)   File "/home/automator/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.5/site-
>   packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.py", line 432, in
>   new_func
>          return func(*args, **kwargs)   File "/home/automator/PycharmProjects/tensorflow/venv/lib/python3.5/site-
>   packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 493, in
>   import_graph_def
>          raise ValueError(str(e))   ValueError: Input 0 of node    import/final_retrain_ops/Wx_plus_b/weights_quant/AssignMinLast was
>   passed float    from
>   import/final_retrain_ops/Wx_plus_b/weights_quant/min:0 incompatible
>   with

expected float_ref.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure your `pb_file` is in the right format (something like [this](https://github.com/timctho/convolutional-pose-machines-tensorflow/blob/master/run_freeze_graph.py)) and also try to have some value in the 'name' parameter of `import_graph_def()` to try and override the "import" default value, like so:

```
# read pb into graph_def
with tf.gfile.GFile(pb_file, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())

# import graph_def
with tf.Graph().as_default() as graph:
    tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
```